# Submit hidden form value automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How do I submit a specific part of the form automatically but without refreshing a page with the value attribute I need to send to server?

The reason I need to do this is to constantly check for match of email addresses from my database but without refreshing the pages....

I know I can use set interval to trigger a function every 0.25 seconds but what else should I insert so that my attribute will send to the server?

Comment: Best way is to use jQuery + AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You should use `$.ajax()` or related method to request information from your server. Ajax will prevent page refresh if used correctly :-)

Comment: use this plugin. [jquery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on keyup event in jquery to get the text in the input field and send it to the server through ajax request.

```
<input type="text" id="email">

<script>
  $("#email").keyup(function(){

    $.ajax({
     url: "server_script.php?email="+encodeURIComponent($(this).val()),
     context: document.body
   }).success(function( response ) {
       // Server response will come here on success
       // Do what ever you like with the response
   });

 });
<script>
```

And in the server side get the email using `$_GET['email']` and once the validation is done do something like `echo "success";`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id = "email">
<script>
$('#email').keydown(function(e){
    var email_value = e.target.value;
    $.post( "ur backend url", { "email": email_value } ).done(function(data){
           //respond here
        });
});
</script>
```

use keydown to trigger and ajax post to check the email.